# WebDriver: Change event not firing

Tags: javascript, testing, knockout.js, webdriver

I have an application that is using KnockoutJS and I'm attempting to write some tests that test a form. If you don't know KnockoutJS, the short story for it is that it provides bindings from my view to my data model. This means that when I type a value in the an input field, my underlying object automatically gets updated with that input fields value. This is done through a change event by default.

The problem I am having is that when my WebDriver test is typing into the field, the change event is not firing so my underlying data model does not have the appropriate values. This causes my form validation to fail when it should not.

I've done everything I could find on the internet to make this work. I've:

1. sent the tab key
2. clicked away from the form field
3. send JavaScript code to fire focus and blur events (validation occurs on blur)
4. clicked the form field before typing
5. set waits just incase it was a timing issue
6. changed KnockoutJS to update input field on afterkeydown

None of these have worked for me.

In addition, I have verified that this is not an event bubbling issue as I removed all other events explicitly, leaving just the KnockoutJS change event.

for the solution i'm looking for is one that works for all browser drivers (... at least the main ones e.g. IE, FF, Chrome, Safari) and does not require the use of jQuery.

How do I solve the problem?

Here is the relevant code I'm using to type values into the field:

```
// find element
WebElement input = this.element.findElement(By.className("controls"))
                               .findElement(By.tagName("input"));

// to set focus?
input.click();

// erase any existing value (because clear does not send any events
for (int i = 0; i < input.getAttribute("value").length(); i++) {
    input.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
}

// type in value
input.sendKeys(text);

// to fire change & blur? (doesnt fire change)
//input.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

// to fire change & blur? (doesnt fire change)
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).click();
```

Comment: So, if I am understanding, it updates the `input` field with each key stroke?

Comment: Forgive me for asking a potentially silly question, but is the page in question working correctly when you manually interact with it in the browser? i.e. If you view the page in the browser, type in the text field and tab out of the text field, is the model being updated?

Comment: @Brian the input field is updated by the user. the underlying data model is updated to the value in the input field when the onchange event fires (at least it is supposed to). And if i change the underlying value in the data model, the input field will be updated to the new value automatically. This is all provided by KnockoutJS.

Comment: @RodneyTrotter yes, it is working as expected in all browsers. Just not when using the browsers through WebDriver. I have since worked around this problem with a kludge that I will post, but I am not going to mark it as the answer for now as I feel there should be a better way.

Comment: @loesak: Can you post the html of your web app? If it is onblur which triggers the updates, it seems very odd that nothing is happening when you explicitly fire the onblur event using javascript.

Comment: @vincebowdren the update happens when the change events triggers, my validation happens when the blur event triggers. To narrow down the problem, I removed the blur event. The issue is with the change event not triggering regardless if the blur event is present or not. I explicitly have to fire the change event to get the updates to occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I believe I have found out my problem. I will fully admit this was PEBKAC. I had forgotten that WebDriver has issues if the browser window is not in active focus on the machine (which is still weird to me). When I was debugging the problem, I was using my editor to step through the code. By running the code normally and without removing focus from the browser, the events fire as expected using all three solutions (tab, click-away, and javascript).

I have an example project showing all three methods, however I am a major noob with git and github and am having problems delivering the project. Once i figure that out, I will share the project with you all.

**EDIT**: Got the example code up on GitHub (https://github.com/loesak/knockout.webdriver.change.event.test). You can either start the project as a webapp in a server and run the test manually or you can run the tests via maven (`mvn clean install`). I didn't put a whole lot of effort into getting this to work robustly so it is assuming you have Firefox installed and port <strike>0808</strike> 8080 is open.

**EDIT**: Fixed stated port number

Comment: Congrats on solving the problem, +1.

Answer (score 5):

So I have found a way to work around this issue for now, but by far do I believe this is the correct solution. This does break my rule about not using jQuery, however I feel this is okay for me as KnockoutJS requires jQuery be loaded. There's probably a plain ol' JavaScript way of doing this. I have tested this with FireFox, Safari, and PhantomJS. I assume it will work just as well in Chrome. I give no promises for Internet Explorer.

I am **NOT** going to mark this answer as the correct answer. The correct solution should be through WebDriver browsers firing the proper events. Only when I believe this is not possible through WebDriver will I mark this as the correct answer.

```
// find element in question
WebElement input = this.element.findElement(By.className("controls"))
                               .findElement(By.tagName("input"));

// click it to fire focus event
input.click();

// erase any existing value
for (int i = 0; i < input.getAttribute("value").length(); i++) {
    input.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
}

// enter in desired text
input.sendKeys(text);

// fire on change event (WebDriver SHOULD DO THIS)
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
        "$(arguments[0]).change(); return true;"
    , input);

// click away to fire blur event
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).click();
```

Comment: If you can provide a reproducible scenario and **prove** this is a problem with the WebDriver, then file a bug.

Comment: so i created a project to reproduce this and in doing so i figured out the problem. in short, its a rooky mistake. I'd link to the demo project but my git noobness is preventing me from checking in the project.